# OpenGL render to texture - resize rtt-texture

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm just pulling my hair out an can't find a hint: my app resizes its RTT texture when needed via glTexImage2d with the new texture resolution.

When upsizing it all looks good.  When downsizing, it looks like the TexCoord mapping of [1.0;1.0] maps to [oldRes.width; oldRes.height].  I'm sure I'm missing something vital, but cannot find it right now.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to call `glViewport (...)` accordingly when you resize your render texture, same as if you resized a window. The viewport mapping is not stored together with the framebuffer/render texture, so you have to set it when you draw into something of a different resolution. Generally you would do this at the same time as you setup your projection and other matrices.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Coleman, but that is done right, else it wouldn't look like the mapping simply is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: oops, that wasn't it, also.  My State Cache simply didn't enable the correct texturing unit on bind, when that texture already was bound (this fix also fixed different other problems).

<strike>I just found it - just too simple: obviously (I'm on NVidia) the texturing unit our RTT texture is bound to needs to be reinitialized after resize (NOT ON INITIAL SIZING).  Unbinding the texture and rebinding it when needed again did the job.</strike>

P.S.: I'm working on a State-Cache that uses all available texturing units - that's why this popped up: the texture was never unbound as my examples use much less textures than there are units... (so no texture gets unbound unless deleted).